# is it good to have lot of small function to remove redundancy

Tags: javascript

I have lot of repeatation in my code for instance lot of repeatation like variable z.

```
var updatealldata = function(data){
    var z = data.totalvalue?data.x:data.y;
    $(k).append(z);
}
var updatesingledate = function(data){
    var z = data.totalvalue?data.x:data.y;
    $(k[x-id=' + newId + ').append(z);
}
```

should i create a lot of function which return z for eg

```
z = zvalue();
var zvalue = function(data){
   return data.totalvalue?data.x:data.y;
}
```

is there any better way ?

Comment: code review !!!, I am not the one who gave you the negative!

Comment: kind of code review. just want to know the best practice is there some methodology do people use for having small function

Comment: is there a reason why i got a negative? i hope stackoverflow is not only for bugs. its for issues faced by programmers?

Comment: I think someone his fingers itching him :D and like every thing in its position

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review, belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely good practice to abstract logic that repeats itself out of functions and into smaller pieces.

- maintainable
- transparent logic

The question is always how small should the abstractions be?

There is a line somewhere between acceptable duplication vs unacceptable complication.

Never-the-less functions that do one thing and that thing well, is good practice to get into.